PySpark where to find logs and how to log properly
I have set up a local (docker) spark cluster as provided by bitnami. Everything is running fine.
I can submit simple spark jobs and run them and i can interact with pyspark.
Now i try to set up basic logging (my sources are stackoverflow and github gist)
Mainly i see 2 ways first:
log4jref = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jref.getLogger(__name__) 

If i am using this in pyspark console i see at least the output in console:
>>> logger.info("something")
24/04/15 14:24:31 INFO __main__: something

If i am using the "cleaner solution":
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("here we go")

i do not see anything returned in pyspark console.
In both cases i do not see my outputs in docker logs spark-spark-worker-1 nor on master docker logs spark-spark-1 (other outputs are there).
I also tried to look in /opt/bitnami/spark/logs
So my question is: where to find my log messages in general? And what of the 2 ways is better? In a first steps i just need a quick way to get feedback from my running code - making it production ready comes later (if not easily possible right from start)
little update
the job that  i am running for test looks like this:
# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("My App") \
   .getOrCreate()

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 100))
log.error("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
log.error(f"THE SUM IS HERE: {rdd.sum()}")
print(f"THE SUM IS HERE: {rdd.sum()}")
print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()

While i see in logs that this job runs successfully i can't see my log entries nor the print.
All this places seem to show the same log:

docker ui (uses API to access logs?)
docker logs (for master and worker)
file /opt/bitnami/spark/work/app-20240416084653-0006/0/stderror on worker

